# Пропущена ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

С Днем рождения Насташка вот тебе ватрушка.

Comment: Две пропущены. Обращение (Насташка) обособляется.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: *С днем рождения, Насташка! Вот тебе ватрушка!*

Comment: Может, Настушка? (для рифмы)

Comment: @М_Г автор вопроса написал *Насташка* и не просил подогнать под рифму.

Comment: Согласен, я должен был адресовать свой вопрос автору. А еще правильней  - Настюшка (если девочку зовут Настей).

Comment: Не могу пройти мимо... *С днем рождения, Настюшка! Получай скорей ватрушкой!* Э... возможны варианты.

Comment: Можно ещё в традиционную мелодию попасть:

_С днём рожденья, Настя, поздравляем тебя - 
С днём рождения, Настюшка, вот ватрушка твоя!_